# heroku local works fine but but not online (Ionic & firebase backend)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, heroku, web-deployment

I'm deploying ionic(v.4) with firebase backend to Heroku but the app can only runs locally, it not working when I ran git push heroku master to build app.

The heroku log shows:
[image]

[image]

[image]

And this is build process:
[image]

[image]

[image]

**Server.js:**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var morgan = require("morgan");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cors = require("cors");

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: "true" }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, PUT");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(express.static("www"));
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.listen(app.get("port"), function () {
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get("port"));
});
```

**package.json:** I have moved typescript and app script from devDependencies to dependencies

```
{
  "name": "english",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.1",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^7.20.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": ">= 0.900 < 0.1100",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.0.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "open": "^7.0.3",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: could you provide your package.json file?

Comment: I have edit my question's post with package.json. Pls check.

Comment: not sure why this is happening, but at build time your app is missing angular/cli dependency as the log says. hope it helps to further investigate the problem

Comment: I have tried to move angular/cli and angular-commpiler/cli to dependencies but it doesn't work to. It gives new error: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'

Comment: try moving all angular dev-dependencies into dependencies. they are needed to build your application and it seems heroku doesn't install dev dependencies

Comment: It still not work :((

Comment: is there still an error?

Comment: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch and still the same errors. It gets more errors

Comment: ah, heroku is bad with that (. it seems you will have to build your app locally. commit the dist folder(probably not in master, but in a separate branch just for heroku pushes) and push the result to heroku with compiled angular app. also don't forget to remove or rename the build script

Comment: I don’t have a dist folder :((

Comment: [link](https://github.com/mailinhpham2401/english_app) . This is my github repo